# Script run under session-setup doesn't know $DESKTOP_SESSION

Tags: lightdm, login-screen, environment-variables, session

I have a Multi-Desktop Environment with Unity and KDE. Because of reasons, I installed only the environments without the specific tools, like `nautilus` or `dolphin`.

Since the users (They are multi-user PCs) needs those tools to work, I've written a script, which installs the specific tools for the environment the user is logged in and removes the others (i.e., the user logged into `KDE`, the script installs `dolphin` and removes `nautilus`). This works quite well, unfortunately the users have to remember to run it.

I wanted to automate this process by adding this script to `lightdm`, by placing a config-file at `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d` looking like this:

```
  [SeatDefaults]
  session-setup-script=/opt/install-tools.sh
```

and performing the check for the environment inside the called script, with:

```
case "$DESKTOP_SESSION" in
    ubuntu)
        do stuff....
        ;
esac
```

but as stated in the heading, the variable isn't set at this point.

I've also tried to add a script which only contained the installing and removing part to the `/usr/share/xsessions` script, but that also failed, since I didn't had root-permission at that point. And I can't change the sudoers rule to enable `apt-get` for non-root users, since I don't want anyone to be able to install software to those maschines.

Does anyone have a soultion for this? Or at least a good idea, how I could fix this?

Comment: Possibly the `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` variable is more accurate for this purpose. Haven't checked if it's set early enough, though.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately it didn't (or maybe I'm just to dumb to check it correctly). But at least I found a workaround. I made a short c-script, which calls the script to install the tools. Since this compiles into a binary I can use SUID and run the command inside as root. At least this does it's job, until I find a sane solution for this problem.

Comment: Great! Another approach might be to always have both nautilus and dolphin installed, and control their visibility via the OnlyShowIn option in .desktop files.